LWR <a href> bind expression issue
I am now trying to design an experience portal using LWR framework,
Based on the documentation below, it shows that in HTML editor, I can directly bind the expression and LWR will populate the content
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/advanced_expressions.htm
However, when I am working on an icon navigation in HTML editor as below. The url is not rendering properly, either I use preview mode or publish mode to navigate.
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center"> 
    <a href="/profile/{!User.userId}">
       <i class="fa-solid fa-user" style="font-size:25px"></i>
    </a>
</div>

This is what I get from my URL

I have tried to only bind the expression text {User.userId} only in the href tag but it is still not populating as static text.
Kindly help on this. Thanks in advanced.

I have no experience with LWR, but I'd try to see if href="{!'/profile/' + User.userId}" works.

@HAlves Hi, thanks for the reply, but if i change the href to this, the URL become this instead /%7b!'/profile/'%20+%20User.userId%7d
